# Brewing timer in Brewing software

Tags: software

There is a lot of software to manage and recipes, do conversions etc. (for example BeerSmith, BeerTools, etc.).

Is there any software that also integrates a timer (that alerts you mash steps, boiling hops, etc.)?

Comment: Also I use an Android app called Brew Timer on my phone. It is great as it allows you to put in all the events you need and then it uses your phone to alert you of an hop addition, etc. It is nice because you don't always have your computer with you or want it that close to the brewing process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of them of them do! Certainly BeerSmith and iBrewmaster have timer functions built in. BeerTools does not, I believe.

Comment: yep, look at the 'timer' tab in beersmith.